# How to replicate HTTP server-client communication using a middleware server to avoid opening ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, system-design

**Current setup:**

1. Client makes a GET /pic call to the server
2. Server given the request takes a picture with a webcam and uploads it to S3 returning URL
3. Client shows the image

**Issue:** My server deployment lab has no way of opening ports for me to access the server remotely.

**Idea:**

Set up S3 with SQS and the process would now be:

1. client puts a message to take a pic onto the queue
2. server checks the queue takes the message and takes the pic
3. client calls AWS to get the latest pic

**Issue:** The drawback is that after the server picks up the message it could take some time between the image is taken and uploaded, thus client calling again to get the image from AWS could show old image

Are there any more obvious options for this type of communication?